# Setting the photometric interpretation tag for a multi-page tiff

Tags: pdf, split, tiff

While trying to convert a multipage document from a tiff to a pdf, I encountered the following problem:

```
↪ tiff2pdf 0271.f1.tiff -o 0271.f1.pdf
tiff2pdf: No support for 0271.f1.tiff with no photometric interpretation tag.
tiff2pdf: An error occurred creating output PDF file.
```

Does anybody know what causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused because one or more of the pages in the multi-page tiff does not have the [photometric interpretation](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/photometricinterpretation.html) tag set. This is a required tag, so that means your tiffs are technically invalid (though I bet they work fine anyway).

To fix this, you must identify the page (or pages) that does not have the photometric interpretation set and fix it.

To identify the page, you can simply run something like:

```
↪ tiffinfo your-file.tiff
```

This will spit out the info for **every** page of your tiff. For each good page, you'll see something like:

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x105c0 (67008)
  Subfile Type: (0 = 0x0)
  Image Width: 1760 Image Length: 2639
  Resolution: 300, 300 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 1
  Compression Scheme: CCITT Group 4
  **Photometric Interpretation: min-is-white**
  FillOrder: msb-to-lsb
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 2639
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Software: ScanFix(TM) Enhanced ImageGear Version:  11.00.024
  DateTime: Mon Oct 31 15:11:07 2005
  Artist: 1996-2001 AccuSoft Co., All rights reserved
```

If you have a bad page, it'll lack the `photometric interpretation` section, and you can fix it with:

```
 ↪ tiffset -d $page-number -s 262 0 your-file.tiff
```

Note that the value of zero is the default for the photometric interpretation key, which is 262. You can see the other values for this key at the link above.

If your tiff has a lot of pages (like mine does), you may not be able to easily identify the bad page by eye. In that case, you can take a brute force approach, setting the photometric interpretation for all pages to the default value.

```
# First, split the tiff into many one-page files
↪ tiffsplit your-file.tiff
# Then, set the photometric interpretation to the default for all pages
↪ find . -name '*.tiff' -exec tiffset -s 262 0 '{}' \;
# Then rejoin the pages
↪ tiffcp *.tiff -o out-file.tiff
```

Lot of dummy work, but gets the job done.