# CURL Download of TIFF Content Not Working

Tags: image, api, curl, php-curl, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to download images from an API and my curl command is not working for TIFF content types. **The API relies on serial numbers and does not include image format.** My plan is to pull the header first, then run CURL again based on the content type. Here's the header I'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Feb 2002 01:02:00 GMT Vary: Accept-Encoding Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 Content-Type: image/tiff;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 2876 Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 23:53:11 GMT Connection: close Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://*.an.agency.gov:* X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

I'm using the below CURL command:

```
curl -X GET https://URL/STUFF/12345678 > /storage/12345678.tiff -H API-KEY
```

I can get JPG content to save correctly as JPG.

Here's what the JPG content headers look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Oct 2008 12:55:33 GMT Vary: Accept-Encoding Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 Content-Type: image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 23:53:05 GMT Connection: close Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://*.an.agency.gov:* X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Kinda stumped here.

**UPDATE:**

I ran a GM Convert command on a downloaded TIF and got the following error:

Improper image header

Any ideas how to fix this? It seems the API is doing something to make the TIFF image displayable in the browser, but it seems to be messing up the file download.

Comment: You're trying to download a TIFF from a URL that you aren't showing using a `curl` command that can't possibly work.

Comment: The API does not accept file extensions, only serial ID's. The response headers will tell you what the content type is.

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of head scratching and investigation, it turns out the issue is with the API itself. The TIFF files are exported with a really important tag missing that causes most programs to say it's screwed up (I suppose it is technically). I figured out what was happening when I decided to give GIMP a shot at reading the file and to my surprise, it could read it and convert it successfully. Graphics Magick and ImageMagick can't deal with TIFFs missing the 'photometric interpretation' tag it seems, but GIMP apparently can. Found a nice little command line solution here:

[Setting the photometric interpretation tag for a multi-page tiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348539/setting-the-photometric-interpretation-tag-for-a-multi-page-tiff)